# Real antisymmetric matrix implementation

Tags: matrix

$x$ is a real antisymmetric matrix and is defined as:

```
Format[x[a_, b_]] := Subscript[x, a, b]
    $Assumptions = 
      x \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]];
    x[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} x @@ Sort@{arg} 
    Format[x[arg__]] := Subscript[x, arg]
```

`x[2,2]` is expected to get zero. That is any repeated indices is zero. How to implement it in the above code?

Comment: `x[a_, b_] := 
  1/2 (Array[A, {5, 5}] - Transpose@Array[A, {5, 5}])[[a, b]]; x[2,2]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following works

```
Format[x[a_, b_]] := Subscript[x, a, b]
$Assumptions = 
  x ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]];
x[arg__] /; SameQ[arg] := 0
x[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} x @@ Sort@{arg}
```

Your `!OrderedQ` test is not triggered for the diagonal elements.